# sipml5 client one side not hanging up

Tags: sipml

I have a `sipml5` web client and I can successfully make a call to it. But when a caller hangs up, the web client is not hanging the call. I think I missed an event for this in the `sipml5` API. I got this error in chrome console,

```
this.o_local_stream.stop is not a function
```

But I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: This happened to me around 2 months back, and somehow I got updated SIPml.js file. It was working till today!! Can you guide me what are the necessary changes I can do to make it work?? **In-case your problem is solved**  :(

Comment: update the library and try again. 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DoubangoTelecom/sipml5/master/release/SIPml-api.js

Answer (score 2):

This happens in chrome versions > 45 due to certain mediastream deprecations. In newer versions of chrome MediaStream.stop() is deprecated and replaced by MediaStreamTrack.stop(). sipML5 API has not yet been modified to accept these changes. 
    https://github.com/DoubangoTelecom/sipml5/issues/231

```
Just checkout this link for more info.
```

Comment: This happened to me around 2 months back, and somehow I got updated SIPml.js file. It was working till today!! Can you guide me what are the necessary changes I can do to make it work ?? :(

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved when I updated the library.

I used: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DoubangoTelecom/sipml5/master/release/SIPml-api.js